# O que seriam Take e Skip em Linq?

Tags: linq, nhibernate

estou fazendo manutenção em um sistema e encontrei um `GetAllQueryable()`, que usa o método `Take()` e `Skip()`. Bem, não sei o que são, nem para que servem, pesquisei mas não encontrei nada na documentação. Alguém saberia dizer para que serve?

Comment: Editado, desculpe-me.

Comment: Ficou claro como eles funcionam e para que eles servem? Pois são ótimos recursos para determinados tipos de consultas, e é importante compreender-los para utiliza-los. Qualquer duvida comente na resposta que assim que possível tento esclarecer.

Comment: Ficou show fera! Não tem como não entender com uma explicação dessas... Muito obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

São dois filtros de consultas [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397926.aspx) ou [Lambda Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397687.aspx) que tem seus equivalentes em SQL, para o caso de serem executados sobre um ORM, como no seu caso o NHibernate:

Considere esta tabela nos exemplos:

```
ID | NOME
---------------------------------------------
1  | Cliente 1
2  | Cliente 2
3  | Cliente 3
4  | Cliente 4
5  | Cliente 5
6  | Cliente 6
7  | Cliente 7
8  | Cliente 8
9  | Cliente 9
10 | Cliente 10
11 | Cliente 11
12 | Cliente 12
```

[**Take**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx)

Retorna um número especificado de elementos adjacentes desde o início de uma seqüência.

Uso:

```
// retorna os 3 primeiros elemento da tabela
var r = Session.QueryOver<Cliente>().Take(3).List();
```

Output:

```
ID | NOME
---------------------------------------------
1  | Cliente 1
2  | Cliente 2
3  | Cliente 3
```

Consulta equivalente SQL (Firebird 2.1):

```sql
SELECT first 3 CL.ID, CL.NOME FROM CLIENTE CL
```

---

[**Skip**:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx)

Ignora um número especificado de elementos em uma seqüência e retorna os elementos restantes.

Uso:

```
// retorna todos os items apartir do 2° elemento da tabela
var r = Session.QueryOver<Cliente>().Skip(2).List();
```

Output:

```
ID | NOME
---------------------------------------------
3  | Cliente 3
4  | Cliente 4
5  | Cliente 5
6  | Cliente 6
7  | Cliente 7
8  | Cliente 8
9  | Cliente 9
10 | Cliente 10
11 | Cliente 11
12 | Cliente 12
```

Consulta equivalente SQL (Firebird 2.1):

```sql
SELECT skip 2 CL.ID, CL.NOME FROM CLIENTE CL
```

---

Uso conjunto:

```
// retorna os 3(take) primeiros elementos apartir do 2°(skip) elemento da tabela
var r = Session.QueryOver<Cliente>().Take(3).Skip(2).List();
```

Output:

```
ID | NOME
---------------------------------------------
3  | Cliente 3
4  | Cliente 4
5  | Cliente 5
```

Consulta equivalente SQL (Firebird 2.1):

```sql
SELECT first 3 skip 2 CL.ID, CL.NOME FROM CLIENTE CL
```

---

> Essas técnicas são utilizadas constantemente, para paginação de consultas, trazendo melhor performance a aplicação. Onde só é obtido da base de dados as linhas desejadas.